# Django custom user model rename username colum

Tags: django

I'm trying to implementing a custom Django user model. Below is my user model. My problem is that in my application I use the email field as the username. But it doesn't work as I would when I use the model I get the following error. `"Unknown column 'users.username' in 'field list'"`

```
class usersManager(BaseUserManager):
    pass


def myoverridenmeta(name, bases, adict):
    newClass = type(name, bases, adict)
    for field in newClass._meta.fields:
        if field.attname == 'last_login':
            field.column = 'lastlogin'
            field.db_column = 'lastlogin'
    return newClass


class users(AbstractUser):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('ID', 'emal', 'password', 'salt', 'subscriptionID')
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    is_anonymous = False
    is_authenticated = True

    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    salt = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='EN')
    regDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    orgID = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    subscriptionID = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    orgConfirmed = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    lastLogin = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = usersManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'
        db_table = 'users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

def get_full_name(self):
    return self.email

__metaclass__ = myoverridenmeta
```

The model is used for custom authentication in Django. Below is my custom authentication class.

```
class AuthenticationBackend:

    # Create an authentication method
    # This is called by the standard Django login procedure
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            # Try to find a user matching your username
            user = users.objects.get(email=username)

            #  Check the password
            if user.password == hashlib.sha256(password + user.salt).hexdigest():
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except users.DoesNotExist:
            # No user was found, return None - triggers default login failed
            return None

    # Required for your backend to work properly - unchanged in most scenarios
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return users.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except users.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: What file is the error coming from (pasting a bit more of the traceback would be useful)? Looks like something involving a `Form`? Can you share the relevant code for that? Also, `REQUIRED_FIELDS` references `emal`, but I assume you meant to put `email`.

Comment: The model is used for custom authentication with Django. The error message comes when I try to login with the custom authentication. I will update my question with my custom authentication class.

Comment: You've run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, right?

Comment: yes i run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate  --run-syncdb`